# How many votes are needed for the President to deport illegal aliens?

Tags: united-states, illegal-immigration

How many votes would the President of US need from the Senate to deport illegal immigrants?

Comment: This post lists two completely unrelated questions; SE posts should only contain one. I'm editing out the second one, if you want to know the answer please post it as a separate question (probably on Law.SE instead of here)

Comment: 0? They are already able to be deported because they are illegally here.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different questions here: theory and practice.

- In **theory**, anyone who is in the country illegally can be deported already. He doesn't need any votes in the Senate (or the House) - **it's already the law of the land**. It simply has not been previously enforced, partly because previous administrations refused to do it for political reasons, and partly because of practical budgetary concerns:
- In **practice**, it costs money (budget) to actually enforce this.

  You have to catch the illegal alien. You have to process and detain them. You have to hold a deportation hearing at immigration court. There are legal steps the illegal aliens can take to extend the process a lot, with appeals etc... I am unsure but most likely you have to pay for actual deportation transportation. [Here's a fairly detailed explanation of the whole process](http://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/deportation-removal-proceedings.html). **This all costs boatloads of money.**

  As such, it is debatable whether Trump administration can do a massive deportation within the current budget for DHS/ICE. If he cannot, he will need to get Congress to pass a law (House to write it and Senate to agree to it, which is how legislative branch works) to fund the deportation enforcement; since funding is the legislative branch's purview.

  For that, he needs a simple majority of votes in both houses (since it's a law he wants, there is no need to worry about getting enough votes to override a veto).

  An extra consideration is filibuster-proofing the Senate vote. Current [cloture rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloture) are 60%, barring any procedural changes to them, so that requires 60 votes assuming quorum.

Comment: A seprarate, interesting question is, whether all the extra padding in deportation process is a matter of law (meaning to change it, a new law is needed to pass in Congress); or merely executive details that Administration can tell DHS/ICE to change at will? I assume the former, but if that's wrong feel free to tell me as that would impact the answer somewhat.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that [the current US government already deported about 400,000 immigrants determined illegal every year](http://www.statisticbrain.com/number-of-u-s-deportations/). So it's not like the immigration laws aren't enforced at all. However, [US immigration courts have a massive backlog](http://qz.com/771583/a-record-half-million-cases-are-waiting-to-be-heard-by-us-immigration-courts/), so throwing more money at them could increase the productivity of the deportation system.

Comment: Regarding the padding, a lot of it is due process.  You wouldn't want officers of the federal government to be able to deport people just by claiming that they're deportable, would you?